# Scroll direction configuration does not persist in NixOS

Tags: nixos, scrolling, settings

The title might be misleading but I did not found a better and shorter way to put it so here is some context.

When I configure the touch-pad to scroll the natural way, it works. As soon as I reboot, it does not anymore. But when I access the settings, it shows the good setting. I have to unselect+reselect the setting to make it work again.

[image: nixos touch-pad scrolling settings]

Any idea what's wrong and how to fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I casually found out that I could add this to my `configuration.nix`:

```
  services.xserver.desktopManager.gnome.extraGSettingsOverrides = ''
    [org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/touchpad]
    natural-scroll=true
  '';
```

I just rebooted and it seems to stick. I don't know if there is a more appropriate way?

Comment: Sounds like the initial behavior is a bug, might be worth reporting.